# EF Code First Declaring Entity relationships 2 fields to the same collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework with Code First. I have a table in my database that stores relationships between users. The table structure looks a lot like this:

- `RequestID`
- `UserFromID`
- `UserToID`

Both `UserFromID` and `UserToID` are foreign keys to my User table.

In my User entity I have a virtual property called `Relationships` setup. I want this property to be a collection of of all `RelationshipRequests` from the table listed above where the current users `UserID` is either the `UserFromID` OR the `UserToID`.

These are my bindings in the context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Relationships).WithRequired(e => e.UserFrom)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserFromID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Relationships).WithRequired(e => e.UserTo)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserToID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But once the relationships are retrieved for a user, the only relationships in the collection are the one's where the users ID is the `UserToID`. I have tried swapping them around in which case the collection only contains the relationships where the users ID is the `UserFromID`. It seems as though the second binding is overriding the first instead of appending to it like I expected. I'm obviously doing this wrong. My question, is there another way to do this binding so that both keys are bound the way I want, or is this something I will have to implement another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you use twice the same property, and of course your second binding overrides the first. You have to create 2 navigation properties on your user model, one for each foreign key

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
.HasMany(e => e.FromRelationships).WithRequired(e => e.UserFrom)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.UserFromID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
.HasMany(e => e.ToRelationships).WithRequired(e => e.UserTo)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.UserToID).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

And on the model you will have something like this

```
public virtual List<Relationships> FromRelationships { get; set; }
public virtual List<Relationships> ToRelationships { get; set; }
```

Comment: Right. I know that I could do this. But in the controller I need them to be a single list. I could take this approach and have my Relationships object return both of them as a single collection but then I run into issues with saving the entities. I would have to save them separately.I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, probably what I would do if I have to keep togheter both lists id to add a type field (from/to) on db.

Comment: To keep them together, what I ended up doing was having the seperate lists (FromRelationships & ToRelationship) and then having a readonly property 'Releationship' that returned a union of the 2 lists.

Comment: That's nice, I have to keep it in mind if i?m faced with a similar problem!